# Python multiprocessing hangs on pool.map

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to apply python multiprocessing module to create multiple spss (.sav) fles.

But, unfortunately it is getting hanged for hours and I have to ultimately forse stop the process to kill the process.

Please find the code snippet below,

```
import csv
import os
import copy
import sys
import savReaderWriter
from functools import partial

def write_to_savfile(metadata_dict, exported_file):
    sav_file_name = exported_file[:-4] + ".sav"
    with savReaderWriter.SavWriter(savFileName=sav_file_name, varNames=metadata_dict['var_names'],
                                           varTypes=metadata_dict['var_types']
                    , varLabels=metadata_dict['var_labs'], missingValues=metadata_dict['miss_vals'],
                                           valueLabels=metadata_dict['value_labels']
                    , measureLevels=metadata_dict['measure'], columnWidths=metadata_dict['col_width'],
                                           formats=metadata_dict['allFmt']
                    , ioLocale='en_US.UTF-8'
                    , ioUtf8=True) as writer:

        try:
            variable_position = metadata_dict["varPostion"]
            template=[-1.7976931345812589e+208]*(len(variable_position))
            stringVars=[metadata_dict['var_names'].index(k) for k, v in metadata_dict['var_types'].items() if v>0]
            for z in stringVars:
                template[z]=u""
            lastCase="-125485698569"
            tline=copy.copy(template)
            outLines = []
            freshStart=0
            fileIn=open(exported_file,"r")
            for lineToProcess in fileIn:
                lineSplit=lineToProcess[:-1].split("~!#")
                if lineSplit[1]!=lastCase and freshStart==0:
                    outLines.append(tline)
                    tline=copy.copy(template)
                    tline[0]=lineSplit[0]
                    #tline[1]=lineSplit[1]
                lastCase=lineSplit[1]
                tline[variable_position[lineSplit[2]]]=lineSplit[3]
                freshStart=0
            outLines.append(tline)
            outLines.pop(0) # First element is the blank template
            print "Writing data to .zsav file for survey "+str(exported_file)
            for record in outLines:
                writer.writerow(record)
            print "done: ",exported_file

        except Exception as e:
            print e
            raise Exception('Failed to create .sav File' + str(e))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sorted_file_names = ['1.csv','2.csv','3.csv']
    metadata_dict = {some dictionary used in the above function}
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count())
    multi_sav_func = partial(write_to_savfile, copy.deepcopy(metadata_dict))
    pool.map(multi_sav_func, sorted_file_names)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Can anyone please give a work-around for the same?

One Update:
When I am trying to do with 2 files

```
sorted_file_names = ['1.csv','2.csv']
```

Everything is file I am getting to spss files (1.sav, 2.sav), but while trying with more than 2 files its is getting stuck.

Comment: So you want to write the same dictionary to all of the files? Why not write one file and then just copy it the number of times you desire? No need for multiprocessing whatsoever.

Comment: @zwer , actually the dictionary provides the header details for the spss (.sav) file, as I want to create multiplease spss (.sav) files so I tried the code like that. So are you suspecting due to this the process is getting stuck for hours? Is there any way to get rid of it?

Comment: What you're doing here is calling the `write_to_savfile()` function in parallel (the number of times depends on the number of CPUs on your system) with the same deep copy of your dictionary and a different filename, and since there is no logic in your function to discriminate/sift the data based on the filename all your processing ends up being the same, save for the output filename in the end. Just call `write_to_savfile(metadata_dict, sorted_file_names[0])` instead and then copy it to the other filenames to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to put the code which uses multiprocessing, inside its own function. It will stop recursively launching new pools when multiprocessing re-imports your module in separate processes:

Comment: I tried to create a seperate function which will include the multiprocessing stuff and called it from the __main__, but the issue still persists.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the issue - he's already protecting it with the `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard ensuring that the enclosed block is executed only once.